# Need to ask about associated querys in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries, the first:

```
SELECT XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD, SUM(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD, MONTH (XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS MES, 
       YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS ANO, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR) + '-1-' + CAST(MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR) , 103)   AS FECHA
FROM XEDETALLES_BODEGA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN xEGRESOS_BODEGA ON XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDEGRESO = xEGRESOS_BODEGA.ID
WHERE (YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) = 2012) AND XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD <> 0
GROUP BY XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD, MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA), YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA)
ORDER BY XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD, MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA), YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA)
```

and the second query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) PRECIOUNIT
FROM XCDETALLES_BODEGA
WHERE (IDPROD = FIRSTQUERY.IDPROD) AND (XFECHA < FIRSTQUERY.FECHA)
ORDER BY XFECHA DESC
```

---

Question:  For every record on the first table I need to get the PRECIOUNIT resulting from the second query after replacing IDPROD and FECHA.

Comment: Please edit your answer to remove the ALL CAPS, and use the code editor to format your code so that it is readable.  Reword your actual question so that it is clearer what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the column returned by the second query to be *added* to the results of the first query, you could simply incorporate your second query into the first one as a *correlated subquery*, like this:

```
SELECT
  XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD,
  SUM(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD,
  MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS MES, 
  YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS ANO,
  CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR) + '-1-' + CAST(MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR), 103) AS FECHA,
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) PRECIOUNIT
    FROM XCDETALLES_BODEGA
    WHERE (XCDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD = XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD)
      AND (XCDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA < CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR) + '-1-' + CAST(MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR), 103))
    ORDER BY XCDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA DESC
  ) AS PRECIOUNIT
FROM XEDETALLES_BODEGA 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xEGRESOS_BODEGA ON XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDEGRESO = xEGRESOS_BODEGA.ID
WHERE (YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) = 2012) AND XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD <> 0
GROUP BY XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD, MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA), YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA)
ORDER BY XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD, MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA), YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA)
;
```

However, there's room for improvement with this query.

First of all, I would introduce shorter table aliases. Just consider this rewrite:

```
SELECT
  xed.IDPROD,
  SUM(xed.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD,
  MONTH(xed.XFECHA) AS MES, 
  YEAR(xed.XFECHA) AS ANO,
  CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(xed.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR) + '-1-' + CAST(MONTH(xed.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR), 103) AS FECHA,
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) PRECIOUNIT
    FROM XCDETALLES_BODEGA AS xcd
    WHERE (xcd.IDPROD = xed.IDPROD)
      AND (xcd.XFECHA < CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(xed.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR) + '-1-' + CAST(MONTH(xed.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR), 103))
    ORDER BY xcdXFECHA DESC
  ) AS PRECIOUNIT
FROM XEDETALLES_BODEGA AS xed
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xEGRESOS_BODEGA AS xeg ON xed.IDEGRESO = xeg.ID
WHERE (YEAR(xed.XFECHA) = 2012) AND xed.IDPROD <> 0
GROUP BY xed.IDPROD, MONTH(xed.XFECHA), YEAR(xed.XFECHA)
ORDER BY xed.IDPROD, MONTH(xed.XFECHA), YEAR(xed.XFECHA)
;
```

Would you agree that shorter aliases make your query more readable?

Another issue is your grouping criteria, in particular these two items:

```
MONTH(xed.XFECHA), YEAR(xed.XFECHA)
```

They certainly make your intention clear, but they also undergo multiple conversions as you are making them back into a `datetime` value. And now we are also using the same `datetime` in the correlated subquery too. These conversions are absolutely unnecessary, because you could go about it the other way round. Instead of extracting the year and the month from a `datetime` and then converting those back to a `datetime`, you could "round down" the datetime to the beginning of the corresponding month. The following expression does just that:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0)
```

Now, when you need to display the month and the year as numeric values, you can extract them from the result of the above expression, since that would give you the same month and year. So, take a look at your query now:

```
SELECT
  xed.IDPROD,
  SUM(xed.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD,
  MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0)) AS MES, 
  YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0)) AS ANO,
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0) AS FECHA,
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) PRECIOUNIT
    FROM XCDETALLES_BODEGA AS xcd
    WHERE (xcd.IDPROD = xed.IDPROD)
      AND (xcd.XFECHA < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0))
    ORDER BY xcd.XFECHA DESC
  ) AS PRECIOUNIT
FROM XEDETALLES_BODEGA AS xed
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xEGRESOS_BODEGA AS xeg ON xed.IDEGRESO = xeg.ID
WHERE (YEAR(xed.XFECHA) = 2012) AND xed.IDPROD <> 0
GROUP BY xed.IDPROD, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0)
ORDER BY xed.IDPROD, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0)
;
```

I know what you may be thinking. The new expression seems to be used too many times, which doesn't make the query look very clean, even less so since the expression is not that short. Can that be helped? Yes, it can. You can use a derived table. Put the joins, the WHERE filter and the necessary columns, including the expression calculating the beginning of a month, into a subselect and let your main query pull data from it. Leave the grouping, the sorting and the correlated subquery in the main SELECT. In short, this is what you might end up with:

```
SELECT
  s.IDPROD,
  SUM(s.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD,
  MONTH(s.XFECHA) AS MES, 
  YEAR(s.XFECHA) AS ANO,
  s.XFECHA,
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) PRECIOUNIT
    FROM XCDETALLES_BODEGA AS xcd
    WHERE (xcd.IDPROD = xed.IDPROD)
      AND (xcd.XFECHA < s.XFECHA
    ORDER BY xcd.XFECHA DESC
  ) AS PRECIOUNIT
FROM (
  SELECT
    xed.IDPROD,
    xed.CANTIDAD,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0) AS FECHA
  FROM XEDETALLES_BODEGA AS xed
    LEFT OUTER JOIN xEGRESOS_BODEGA AS xeg ON xed.IDEGRESO = xeg.ID
  WHERE (YEAR(xed.XFECHA) = 2012) AND xed.IDPROD <> 0
) s
GROUP BY s.IDPROD, s.XFECHA
ORDER BY s.IDPROD, s.XFECHA
;
```

However, if you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, you don't need a derived table – you can use CROSS APPLY instead. Here:

```
SELECT
  xed.IDPROD
  SUM(xed.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD,
  MONTH(s.XFECHA) AS MES, 
  YEAR(s.XFECHA) AS ANO,
  s.XFECHA,
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) PRECIOUNIT
    FROM XCDETALLES_BODEGA AS xcd
    WHERE (xcd.IDPROD = xed.IDPROD)
      AND (xcd.XFECHA < s.XFECHA
    ORDER BY xcd.XFECHA DESC
  ) AS PRECIOUNIT
FROM XEDETALLES_BODEGA AS xed
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xEGRESOS_BODEGA AS xeg ON xed.IDEGRESO = xeg.ID
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, xed.XFECHA), 0) AS FECHA
) AS s
WHERE (YEAR(xed.XFECHA) = 2012) AND xed.IDPROD <> 0
GROUP BY xed.IDPROD, s.XFECHA
ORDER BY xed.IDPROD, s.XFECHA
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably throw the first query into a CTE and join it to your second query.

```
;WITH 
 FIRSTQUERY (IDPROD, CANTIDAD, MES, ANO, FECHA)
 AS
 (
  SELECT XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD
    ,SUM(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD
    ,MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS MES
    ,YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS ANO
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR) + '-1-' + CAST(MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) AS VARCHAR) , 103) AS FECHA
  FROM XEDETALLES_BODEGA 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN xEGRESOS_BODEGA ON XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDEGRESO = xEGRESOS_BODEGA.ID
  WHERE (YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA) = 2012) AND XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD <> 0
  GROUP BY XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD, MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA),     YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA)
  ORDER BY XEDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD, MONTH(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA), YEAR(XEDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA)
 )
SELECT TOP (1) XCDETALLES_BODEGA.PRECIOUNIT
FROM XCDETALLES_BODEGA
LEFT JOIN FIRSTQUERY on FIRSTQUERY.IDPROD = XCDETALLES_BODEGA.IDPROD
WHERE XCDETALLES_BODEGA.XFECHA < FIRSTQUERY.FECHA
ORDER BY XFECHA DESC
```